# Pylint highlight and hovering bug on VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

VSCode doesn't highlight the linting problems.

Only highlights the "first letter".

There is no hovering option on the error also.

I tried to uninstall and install again python and/or vscode, with no success.

[image: Pylint bug]

The problems of pylint appear in the problems section on vscode so it is indeed working, just not as intended.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is caused by the VSCode, You can downgrade the VSCode to version [1.61.2](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_61) to avoid this problem.

[image]

[issue page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18027) on github.

Comment: @Ventura Have you solved the problem? if this is helpful, could you accept this answer? thanks, and have a good day : )

Answer (score 0):

Pylint need the library to be installed in its environment, so you need to install `networkx` and `bs4` in the environment where pylint is ran (probably your virtualenv, or the virtualenv vscode is using).

Comment: I think you missunderstood the post. Does not matter which type of error it is, the problem is Pylint is not highlighting the whole "word", and also I cant hover and check the error (by getting a "box" of text), nothing appears. All libraries are installed in the same environment

Comment: Ho you should probably open issues in the vscode extension you're using or [pylint](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint) (it gives a column and not a range) then. Because this is not about bad configuration on your side.